# How to configure redux-persist not to persist store on public routes in React

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist to saving the store in localStorage in a web project using react and redux-toolkit.

My react app has public and private routes. The public ones are routes for sign-in, reset-password, and similar ones.

I want to configure redux-persist to be aware of the routes and not to persist the store if a user is on a public route. How to achieve this?

Comment: Your redux store doesn't know or care what page you are on.  You need to design your state such that the persisted properties come from a different property of the state than the non-persisted ones.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to design a store in such manner? 

I am was thinking of somehow sending an action to redux-persist not to persist a store when components behind public routes get rendered